# Iterating through columns in a csv file to find number of occurrences for an item - PYTHON

Tags: python, csv, duplicates, counter

### I have three columns in a csv file (Excel spreadsheet):

**name  place   value**

fal6s hlkshf8 alksj0

saljg h9ag80a ha8g9a

lak5f agk1h00 ha035a

---

and so on (thousands of data points long)

there are duplicates in the columns name and place.

i want to find how many places are associated with just one name.

for e.g. for name 'algh9g0' i want to count how many places are tagged to it

I think I need to use Counter() or defaultdict().

so far I have:

```
from  collections import Counter
with open('/Users/tb/Desktop/blah.csv', 'r') as f:
    EXP = csv.reader(f)
    HEADERS = next(EXP)     #skip over column titles
    for row in EXP:
        counts = Counter(row[1])     
        print counts ... for every unique name
```

but its not giving me what i want.
i'm trying to say: for every name in column 1, count the number of places which are located in column 2.

its printing:

```
Counter({'6': 2, '9': 2, '8': 2, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1, '0': 1, '7': 1})
```

as if it's splitting up the items.

Thanks

Comment: Your code has an undefined variable `row`. Please post your _actual_ code.

Comment: ah that is because row is being treated like a list and row is literally a row in the excel spreadsheet...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you posted has a bug and doesn't even run. Also, making a new `Counter` for each line is certainly a problem if you want to keep some overall counts. Also I'm assuming that your input data is really comma-separated; the sample you pasted appears to be space or tab-separated.

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to find out how many *different* places are associated with a single name. The idea is that for each name we've encountered, we keep a `set` of places that it has been associated with. Then in the end, we loop through each name and print the size of the places-set.

```
import csv

name_places = {} # map from name to set of places

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
    EXP = csv.reader(f)
    HEADERS = next(EXP)
    for (name, place, value)  in EXP:
        name_places.setdefault(name, set())
        name_places[name].add(place)

for name, places in name_places.items():
    print('%s,%d' % (name, len(places)))
```

Comment: your interpretation is correct! I'm new to stack overflow and I couldn't attach my excel spreadsheet to the question, hence the difficulty in expressing :/ the data is literally three long columns full of mixed letters and numbers like akgha898 where the first column represents names, second places and third values ( but for this problem we dont care about values )

Comment: @John welcome. Please read [mcve] and [ask] to get more accommodated:)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `defaultdict` and no csv reader:

## data.csv

```
name place value
fal6s hlkshf8 alksj0
saljg h9ag80a ha8g9a
lak5f agk1h00 ha035a
lak5f agk1h00 ha035a
fal6s hlkshf8 alksj0
fal6s hlkshf8 alksj0
fal6s hlkshf8 alksj0
```

## code

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(set)
with open('data.csv') as f:
    headers = next(f).split()
    for line in f:
        name, place, _ = line.split()
        res[name].add(place)

for name, places in res.iteritems():
    print name, len(places)
```

## Output:

```
saljg 1
lak5f 2
fal6s 3
```